# How come new_duration prints out as blank not allowing my loop to run?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using AutoHotKey's latest release of v1.1

I pass 3 arguments to the program from the commandline:
`key`, `duration`, and `window` saved in `%1%`, `%2%`, and `%3%` respectively.

When printing key duration and window using `MsgBox, %1% %2% %3%`
I get correct values of lets say in this case `a 5 Untitled`

```
duration := %2%
new_duration := (duration * 1000)

MsgBox, %new_duration%

while (A_TickCount - start <= new_duration)
{
    ControlSend,,{Blind}{%1% down}{Blind}{%1% up},%3%
    sleep 50
}
```

When the above code is executed it prints nothing not allowing my loop to run.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation a bit more carefully and found `A_Args[index]`

Completed code:

```
key := A_Args[1]
duration := (A_Args[2] * 1000)
window := A_Args[3]


while (A_TickCount - start <= duration)
{
    ControlSend,,{Blind}{%key% down}{Blind}{%key% up},%window%
    sleep 50
}
```